# Scala: Naming parameters of function parameters

Tags: scala, delegates, functional-programming

I have an `Image` trait that represents a 2D ARGB image. `Image` has a `map` method which takes a mapping function and transforms the image using said function. The mapping function has 3 parameters: the X and Y coordinates and the color of the image at that coordinate. The color is represented as a 32-bit ARGB value packed into an `Int`.

```
trait Image {
    def map(f: (Int, Int, Int) => Int)
}
```

However, without a comment, it's impossible to tell which parameter of `f` is which.

In C#, I would create a delegate for this, which allows me to name the parameters of the mapping function:

```
delegate int MapImage(int x, int y, int color);
```

Is there anything of this sort in Scala? Is it being considered for addition to the language? Without it, I cannot write an interface that is readable without explicit documentation.

(Note: I know I should wrap the `Int` in a case class for the purposes of representing a color, but this is just an illustrative example.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you make custom function types in Scala with named parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644840/how-can-you-make-custom-function-types-in-scala-with-named-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a trait that `f` implements. With SAM support (enabled if you compile with `-Xexperimental`, and will be in the next version) this should be just as easy to use.

```
trait ImageMapper {
  def mapImage(x: Int, y: Int, color: Int): Int
}

trait Image {
  def map(f: ImageMapper) = ...
}

myImage.map{ (x, y, color) => ... } //the anonymous function
// is automatically "lifted" to be an implementation of the trait.
```

Comment: I didn't know about SAM, it sounds like something I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps through using types:

```
trait Image {
  type x = Int
  type y = Int
  type color = Int

  def map(f: (x, y, color) => Int)
}
```

I'd much rather using case class like so:

```
case class MapImage(x: Int, y: Int, color: Int)
trait Image {
  def map(f: MapImage => Int)
}
```